# Any limitation of tiff file size in Heroku app?

Tags: heroku

I want to deploy my app which calls 2 gigabyte tiff file to free-heroku.
Is it possible?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. Heroku limits the slug size of your application to [500mb compressed](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size).

Even if compression gets you under the 500mb limit, having a large application slug will really slow down your deploy process. A better approach would be to use a service [like Amazon S3 for your application's asset storage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).